# Password Box with Hint Text

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, windows-phone-7.1, hint, passwordbox

How to display a password box with hint text in windows phone?

I have tried the `PasswordBox` and `Toolkit's PhoneTextBox`. Is there anything special to be done to combine the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this I am using http://damianblog.com/2011/01/21/wp7-password-watermark/ for now. I hope to get a better method.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: [WindowsPhoneControls](http://github.com/JoshClose/WindowsPhoneControls)

Also, the next release of the Telerik WP controls has a RadPasswordTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ,  try to edit phonetextbox's control template . replace the textbox with passwordbox.

and you can get a passwordbox edition phonetextbox , LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own WatermarkedPasswordBox which will be deliver from PasswordBox. It is not difficult. This link will help you :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/create-a-watermark-textbox-effect-from-window-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

**In Windows Phone 8 using [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)**

**En Xaml**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,0,0" x:Name="ContentPanel">             
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Height="72" Margin="0,0,0,270" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Hint="{Binding LocalizedResources.LblUser, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" x:Name="txtUser" />
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Height="72" Margin="0,0,0,210" TextWrapping="Wrap" Hint="{Binding LocalizedResources.LblPassword, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" x:Name="txtPasswordPlace" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" />            
        <PasswordBox Margin="0,72,0,210" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="txtPassword" LostFocus="PasswordLostFocus" GotFocus="PasswordGotFocus" Opacity="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.LblStartSession, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Click="BtnLogin_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,150" />            
    </Grid
```

**En C#**

```
    public void CheckPasswordWatermark()
    {
        var passwordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Password);
        txtPasswordPlace.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 100 : 0;
        txtPassword.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 0 : 100;
    }

    private void PasswordGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtPasswordPlace.Opacity = 0;
        txtPassword.Opacity = 100;
    }

    private void PasswordLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckPasswordWatermark();
    }
```

**Happy Coding!**